# How can I keep the Eclipse debugger from automatically expanding the Package Explorer into libraries on exceptions?

Tags: eclipse, exception, package, explorer

I love when the Eclipse debugger halts the process and expands the Package Explorer to highlight the line in my source code when I cause a null pointer exception or other error, but I hate it when it attempts to do that for exceptions occurring within libraries for which I do not have linked source. In those cases it opens the Package Explorer deeply to that point (often deep within Android 2.1 SDK). This causes me to have to close the tree back up, and it shows an unhelpful tab for the corresponding class file that I also must close. Is it possible to retain the useful behavior only for exceptions happening in available source files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a double arrow (<-->) on top of the package explorer. If you un-check this, Eclipse won't focus the stack Package explorer when a resource is opened.

You can also choose what to show in the package explorer.  In the package explorer menu (top right of the view, beside the double arrow), choose Filters... If you disable (select) Libraries from external, then the package explorer won't show the libraries (and thus won't expand them).  However, this means that no libraries will be shown (not even ones with source). This isn't exactly what you want, but it might help.

Comment: I hadn't known what that button was for so that is indeed a helpful tip. Unfortunately I value more the automatic jumping into my code when it hits an exception in my code and I would be sad to give that up.

Comment: This question got me thinking a bit ;-). You might also be able to use filters. I've updated my answer to describe them.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Two minds beating as one. I was fooling with the filters too and have made some recommended changes. I've not tested any of those changes. Have you tested your suggestion? I have taken your suggestion which seems the most likely solution and am marking it as the best answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I did test it (that is, I disabled 'external libraries' and did some debugging and it didn't expand into the libraries). I'm going to work this way myself since I always find the big expansion into the libraries to be hard to follow.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you @irbull for a solution to a very annoying problem. You certainly deserve the bounty!